# Paint.NET - override default settings?

Tags: paint.net

Whenever I open Paint.NET, the smoothing, anti-aliasing and flood fill % settings are always enabled. Can I override the program's settings so that these are instead disabled by default? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help: [Paint.NET Settings](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/29946-is-there-any-way-to-change-the-defaults-for-paintnet/).
Apparently, there is no other way to change default settings on Paint.NET. You can only change things there.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Luciano That is exactly what I did, there is really not much to say. There is no way to change the default settings. The Page I linked is just a reference that confirms my answer.